# Entity Framework 4.0 Mapping POCOS with different property names from db fields names

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity

I'm a newbie to ADO.Net Entity framework 4.  I have a set of pocos which I need to map to a legacy database.  The problem is that the db field names are different to the poco property names. eg. db field name = 'cusID' and poco property = 'CustomerID'.
What is the best way to map these?

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly the problem EF mapping is designed to solve.

Your POCO class need to match your 'conceptual model'... Not your 'data model'.

If in EF you build your model from the database you simply need to rename your entity properties. Doing this changes the conceptual model - to match your POCO classes - but leaves the storage model unchanged, and sets up the appropriate mappings.

Comment: Yes, but how? Using Poco, I cannot find a way to do it either. See this post also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219609/customized-mapping-in-poco-of-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Framework CTP4** has a new feature called **Code First** that allows you to map POCO property members to database table column names. This blog article may be what you are looking for,

http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/07/28/how-to-map-pocos-to-existing-databases-in-entity-framework-4-0-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-2/

Additionally, EF CTP 5 - which will be released in the next few weeks - has a better API to fluently configure your own **conventions** to map your POCO domain classes to existing database structures.

Hope this helps.

**Update** Here is the new article that discusses how to achieve this in EF4 **CTP5**

Comment: Not only is there no link for the update, but the original link is now a dead link as well. This is why it is preferred to answer the question in your answer and not to a link offsite. Answers will remain long after bloggers rearrange or shut down.

Comment: @Godeke The article has since been removed as it is obselete. It was written pre release of EF 4. EF is now on the 5 release and the material described is no longer valid I believe.